# Retrieve diagonal values from a 2d array

Tags: javascript, arrays, matrix

I'm trying to create a function that retrieves the diagonal values from a 2-d array:

```
input = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [5, 1, 2, 3],
    [9, 5, 1, 2]
]

output = [[9], [5, 5], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3], [4]]
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how to manipulate the indices in a nested loop... This is what I'm currently working with:

```
const diagonalValues = arr => {
    let output = new Array(2*input.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
        output[i] = [];
        if (i < input.length) {
            for (j = input.length-1; j>i-input.length; --j) {
                console.log(i, j)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: What about the other direction?  `[1],[2,5],[3,1,9],[4,2,5],[3,1],[2]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use get number of rows which is just number of arrays and number of columns which is number of elements in each inner array (assuming all arrays have the same number of elements), and based on that calculate the diagonal matrix.

```js
const input = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [5, 1, 2, 3],
  [9, 5, 1, 2]
]

const rows = input.length;
const columns = input[0].length;
const total = columns + rows - 1;
const result = [];

for (let i = rows - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  const row = input[i];

  for (let j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
    const el = input[i][j];
    const pos = j + rows - i - 1;

    if (!result[pos]) {
      result[pos] = []
    }

    result[pos].unshift(el)
  }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
```

You can do the same with `reduceRight` and `forEach` methods.

```js
let input = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 4],
  [5, 1, 2, 8, 3],
  [9, 5, 1, 2, 2],
  [9, 5, 1, 2, 1]
]
const result = input.reduceRight((r, a, i) => {
  a.forEach((e, j) => {
    const pos = j + (input.length - i - 1)
    if(!r[pos]) r[pos] = []
    r[pos].unshift(e)
  })

  return r;
}, []);

console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
```

Comment: This doesn't work with other inputs (e.g. the one in my answer).

Comment: @junvar I think it does, you can just use `reverse` if you want in different order.

Comment: @junvar Or just unshift instead of push.

Comment: you're right, I thought for a moment it failed for arrays taller than they are wide, but I was mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this algorithm to retrieve the diagonal values from 2d-input array.

```js
 const input = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [5, 1, 2, 3],
    [9, 5, 1, 2]]

    let output = []
    input.forEach(res => {
        res.forEach(resp => {
        // if length of array is equel to 1
            if (output.filter(x => x == resp).length > 0) {
                output.filter(x => x == resp)[0].push(resp)
              //if length of array is greater than 1
            } else if (output.filter(x => x[0] == resp).length > 0) { 
                output.filter(x => x[0] == resp)[0].push(resp)
            } else {
              let temp = []
              temp.push(resp)
              output.push(temp)
            }
        })
    })
    output.forEach(o => console.log(JSON.stringify(o)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let input = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [5, 1, 2, 8],
  [9, 5, 1, 2],
  [9, 5, 1, 2],
  [9, 5, 1, 2],
];

let out = [];
for (let i = 1 - input.length; i < input[0].length; i++) {
  let o = [];
  let y = Math.max(-i, 0);
  let x = Math.max(i, 0);
  while (x < input[0].length && y < input.length)
    o.push(input[y++][x++]);
  out.push(o)
}

out.forEach(o => console.log(JSON.stringify(o)));
```